# how to add a row in the table programmatically in the laravel blade using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I'm completely new in laravel and i am trying to make a form in it that contain a bottom make new row in a table in the form . 
here is my script:

```
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("AcademicDegreeTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell4.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

and:

```
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

But when i click at this button the new row appears for a short time and then when the page reload that is gone.

Routes:

```
Route::get('/form' , 'FormController@index')->name('form');
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('form');
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use PHP at all to do this? Is there some db persistence involved?

Comment: If you want a row to persist after you reload the page, then you need to store it in a db of sorts. Is that what you want? It's very unclear by your question.

Comment: If you just need to make an update on the UI after you make the call, use AJAX to make your request call and update the UI as needed. Or else, return the data you sent in the laravel view and use laravel templating to update UI

Comment: thank you jared for ur attention . i just meant that i wanna create a row (or any other html elements) programmatically by clicking in the button in a blade.php file . there is no  db persistence since there isn't need to it .

Comment: then probably your question has wrong tag to `laravel` this is pure javascrip/jquery problem and you can achieve this easily by following my comment

Comment: yes it is exactly what i want to do

Comment: thank you vishal , but it work fine when i dont use laravel . i wondered why the page must reload at all

Comment: Your question specifically mentions when you **reload the page** that your changes are lost which implies you want to **keep** or **persist** them, no??? For this you must use some sort of data store - web storage, cache, db, etc. We need to understand if you need the added rows for while just on that page or permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your button is within a form, the default behaviour is that clicking the button submits the form. To prevent it, the `onclick` handler has to return `false`:

```
<button class="button" onclick="return myFunction()">
```

and

```
function myFunction() {
  //...
  return false;
}
```

Anyway, you could better use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **cookies** or put row count value in **session**  else there is a **[Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)** concept in html you can use it also.